# How to validate a checkbox in ZF2

Tags: zend-framework, zend-framework2

I've read numerous workarounds for Zend Framework's lack of default checkbox validation.

I have recently started using ZF2 and the documentation is a bit lacking out there.

Can someone please demonstrate how I can validate a checkbox to ensure it was ticked, using the Zend Form and Validation mechanism? I'm using the array configuration for my Forms (using the default set-up found in the example app on the ZF website).

Comment: Do you want to mark the form invalid if the checkbox isn't checked?

Comment: That's correct, yes it's a Terms checkbox that must be checked. There's no clearcut way of doing it from what I've seen..

Comment: Since checkboxes are typically optional fields, omitting them won't make the form fail.  You can make a custom validtor for the checkbox field that requires the value of that form element to be the value of the checkbox.  When the cb isn't checked, the value will be empty, when its checked, it will be whatever the value is.  You could also do it in code by getting the post value of the checkbox field and if its empty mark the form as invalid.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Try this

Form element :

```
$this->add(array(
            'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Checkbox',
            'name' => 'agreeterms',
            'options' => array(
                'label' => 'I agree to all terms and conditions',
                'use_hidden_element' => true,
                'checked_value' => 1,
                'unchecked_value' => 'no'
            ),
        ));
```

In filters, add digit validation

```
use Zend\Validator\Digits; // at top

$inputFilter->add($factory->createInput(array(
                        'name' => 'agreeterms',
                        'validators' => array(
                            array(
                                'name' => 'Digits',
                                'break_chain_on_failure' => true,
                                'options' => array(
                                    'messages' => array(
                                        Digits::NOT_DIGITS => 'You must agree to the terms of use.',
                                    ),
                                ),
                            ),
                        ),
                    )));
```

Comment: cool thanks a lot. Was just about to start a new project, look forward to trying it out.

Comment: A nice, elegant solution given that ZF2 is continually and intentionally making common, everyday tasks as difficult and cumbersome as possible to implement.

Answer (score 9):

You could also just drop the hidden form field (which I find a bit weird from a purist HTML point of view) from the options instead of setting its value to 'no' like this:

```
$this->add(array(
        'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Checkbox',
        'name' => 'agreeterms',
        'options' => array(
            'label' => 'I agree to all terms and conditions',
            'use_hidden_element' => false
        ),
    ));
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and did something similar to [Optimus Crew's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14874347/1612219) but used the Identical Validator.

If you don't set the `checked_value` option of the checkbox and leave it as the default it should pass in a '1' when the data is POSTed. You can set it if you require, but make sure you're checking for the same value in the `token` option of the validator.

```
$this->filter->add(array(
        'name' => 'agreeterms',
        'validators' => array(
            array(
                'name' => 'Identical',
                'options' => array(
                    'token' => '1',
                    'messages' => array(
                        Identical::NOT_SAME => 'You must agree to the terms of use.',
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ));
```

This won't work if you use the option `'use_hidden_element' => false` for the checkbox for the form. If you do this, you'll end up displaying the default NotEmpty message `Value is required and can't be empty`

Answer (score 3):

This isn't directly related to the question, but here's some zf2 checkbox tips if you're looking to store a user's response in the database...

1. **DO** use '1' and '0' strings, don't bother trying to get anything else to work. Plus, you can use those values directly as SQL values for a bit/boolean column.
2. **DO** use hidden elements. If you don't, no value will get posted with the form and no one wants that.
3. **DO NOT** try to filter the value to a boolean. For some reason, when the boolean value comes out to be false, the form doesn't validate despite having `'required' => false;`

Example element creation in form:

```
$this->add([
    'name' => 'cellPhoneHasWhatsApp',
    'type' => 'Checkbox',
    'options' => [
        'label' => 'Cell phone has WhatsApp?',
        'checked_value' => '1',
        'unchecked_value' => '0',
        'use_hidden_element' => true,
    ],
]);
```

Example input filter spec:

```
[
    'cellPhoneHasWhatsApp' => [
         'required' => false,
     ],
]
```

And here's an example if you want to hide some other form fields using bootstrap:

```
$this->add([
    'name' => 'automaticTitle',
    'type' => 'Checkbox',
    'options' => [
        'label' => 'Automatically generate title',
        'checked_value' => '1',
        'unchecked_value' => '0',
        'use_hidden_element' => true,
    ],
    'attributes' => [
        'data-toggle'     => 'collapse',
        'data-target'     => '#titleGroup',
        'aria-expanded'   => 'false',
        'aria-controls'   => 'titleGroup'
    ],
]);
```

I'm a ZF2 fan, but at the end of the day, you just have to find out what works with it and what doesn't (especially with Forms). Hope this helps somebody!

Answer (score 1):

Very old question, but figured it might still be used/referenced by people, like me, still using Zend Framework 2. (Using [ZF 2.5.3](https://github.com/zendframework/zendframework/releases/tag/release-2.5.3) in my case)

[Jeff's answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39885325/1155833) helped me out getting the right config here for what I'm using. In my use case I require the Checkbox, though leaving it empty will count as a 'false' value, which is allowed. His answer helped me allow the `false` values, especially his:

> DO NOT try to filter the value to a boolean. For some reason, when the boolean value comes out to be false

The use case is to enable/disable certain entities, such as Countries or Languages so they won't show up in a `getEnabled[...]()` Repository function.

**Form element**

```
$this->add([
    'name' => 'enabled',
    'required' => true,
    'type' => Checkbox::class,
    'options' => [
        'label' => _('Enabled'),
        'label_attributes' => [
            'class' => '',
        ],
        'use_hidden_element' => true,
        'checked_value' => 1,
        'unchecked_value' => 0,
    ],
    'attributes' => [
        'id' => '',
        'class' => '',
    ],
]);
```

**Input filter**

```
$this->add([
    'name' => 'enabled',
    'required' => true,
    'validators' => [
        [
            'name' => InArray::class,
            'options' => [
                'haystack' => [true, false],
            ],
        ],
    ],
])
```