# zf2 Checkbox rendering by formInput fails

Tags: php, checkbox, zend-framework2, zend-form

I want to make a chekbox for terms of use. I've found an interesting solution, given by a webcoder [How to validate a checkbox in ZF2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13459581/how-to-validate-a-checkbox-in-zf2)

The case is that I have a difficult HTML structure, that's why I can't use neither formRow, nor formCollection to render. I'm trying to use the following approach instead:

```
$agreement = $form->get('agreement');
echo $this->formInput($agreement);
echo $this->formElementErrors($agreement);
```

And I receive the empty value:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="agreement" class="checkbox" value="">
```

I also tried to add hidden field, but my attempt also failed:

```
$agreement = $form->get('agreement');
echo $this->formHidden($agreement);
echo $this->formInput($agreement);
echo $this->formElementErrors($agreement);
```

The html is:

```
<input type="hidden"   name="agreement" class="checkbox" value="">
<input type="checkbox" name="agreement" class="checkbox" value="">
```

As a result I receive errors about "Value is required and can't be empty"

May be someone can give me a tip how to properly render checkbox in my case?

code of my inputFilter:

```
<?php
namespace Auth\Form;

use Zend\InputFilter\InputFilter;
use Zend\Validator\Digits;

class UserFormFilter extends InputFilter {

    public function __construct() {

        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'agreement',
            'validators' => array(
                array(
                    'name' => 'Digits',
                    'break_chain_on_failure' => true,
                    'options' => array(
                        'messages' => array (
                            Digits::NOT_DIGITS => 'You must agree to the terms of use.',
                        )
                    ),
                ),

            ),
        ));
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Can you add the code of your InputFilter?

Comment: added, I used the one, provided in the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13459581/how-to-validate-a-checkbox-in-zf2

Comment: Might be worth reading the docs on usage of the `formCheckbox` view helper and using that instead if `formInput` -> http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.form.elements.html#checkbox

Comment: Thank you, Crisp, you are right, I wasn't attentive enough. Thank you for your answer and attention!

Answer (score 0):

Check this out please.

```
$this->add(array(
        'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Checkbox',
        'name' => 'agreeterms',
        'options' => array(
            'label' => 'I agree to all terms and conditions',
            'use_hidden_element' => true,
            'checked_value' => 1,
            'unchecked_value' => 'no'
        ),
        'attributes' => array(//the difference is here
            'value' => 'yes'
        )
    ));
```

if you add the ***attributes array*** it should work.